# Unity EditorGUILayout.EnumMaskField problems when first enum value is 0

Tags: c#, enums, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a Unity editor. I have a set of flags in an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Flags : int
{
    None = 0x00,
    First = 0x01,
    Second = 0x02,
    Third = 0x04,
    Fourth = 0x08
}
```

which I want to present in a drop down list, where the user can select more than one of these flags. I found EditorGUILayout.EnumMaskField, and I'm using it.

By default, it presents the "Nothing" and "Everything" options to me. Not only do I not want them: they seem to cause problems for me, due to the "Nothing" option it provides being 0 and my own "None" option also being 0. Removing the "None" flag is not an option due to other reasons in the application, neither setting the "None" option to something else than 0.

I'm initializing the selected flags when creating the window from a set Flags object. In the Flags object that I bring into the editor the flags "First" and "Second" are on, but when the EnumMaskField is drawn, the "None" and "First" are instead selected. As if "None" would be "First", and "First" would be "Second".

```
private static Flags myFlags;

public static MyEditorWindow ShowWindow(Flags flags)
{
    myFlags = flags;
    ...
}

public void OnGUI()
{
    myFlags = (Flags)EditorGUILayout.EnumMaskField("Flags:", myFlags);
}
```

Is there any way to disable the "Nothing" and "Everything" options?

Answer (score 0):

Has the same issue,

Here you can find explanation why so happens and solution:
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/editorguilayout-enummaskfield-can-invent-values-for-your-enum.388809/

In your case it could be resolved by this line of code:

```
myFlags = (Flags)((int)(Flags)EditorGUILayout.EnumMaskField("Flags:", (Flags)((int)(myFlags) << 1)) >> 1);
```